# NgRx Select Errors When Attempting Access on Nested Properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm getting TypeErrors when using NgRx select functions when accessing nested properties.

I have my root store configured in `app.module.ts` like this:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ app: appReducer }),
```

where app reducer is just a standard reducer. It sets the state correctly; I can see that in the redux dev tools. The selectors for some nested properties that are erroring are:

```
const getAppFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<IAppState>('app');

export const getAppConfig = createSelector(getAppFeatureState, state => {
  return state.appConfig.data;
});

export const getConfigControls = createSelector(getAppConfig, state => {
  console.log({ state }) // logs values from initial state
  return state.controls;
});

export const getConfigDropdowns = createSelector(
  getConfigControls,
  state => state.dropdowns,
);
```

When I subscribe to these selectors in `app.compontent.ts` like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new appActions.LoadAppConfig());
  this.store
    .pipe(select(appSelectors.getConfigDropdowns))
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('OnInit Dropdowns Data: ', data);
    });
}
```

> `app.component.ts:31 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdowns' of null
>       at app.selectors.ts:18`

When I add logging to the selectors higher up the chain, I can see that the only elements logged are the `initialState` values, which are set to null. I don't think this selector function should fire until the value changes from its initial value. But since it doesn't, its unsurprising that I'm getting this error, since it is trying to access a property on null. Is it a necessity that `initialState` contain the full tree of all potential future nested properties in order not to break my selectors?

#### How can I prevent this selector firing when its value is unchanged?

Also, Is the `StoreModule.forRoot` configured correctly? It is somewhat puzzling to me that creating a "root" store, creates the `app` key in my redux store parallel to my modules' stores, ie, the module stores are not underneath `app`.

#### Edit:

Adding general structure of `app.reducer.ts`. I use [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) to shorten boilerplate necessary for updating nested properties, however I have tried this reducer also as the more traditional kind with spread operator all over the place and it works identically.

```
import produce from 'immer';

export const appReducer = produce(
  (
    draftState: rootStateModels.IAppState = initialState,
    action: AppActions,
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case AppActionTypes.LoadAppConfig: {
        draftState.appConfig.meta.isLoading = true;
        break;
      }
      /* more cases updating the properties accessed in problematic selectors */
      default: {
        return draftState; // I think this default block is unnecessary based on immer documentation
      }
    }
}
```

#### Edit: Add `initialState`:

```
const initialState: rootStateModels.IAppState = {
  user: null,
  appConfig: {
    meta: {isError: false, isLoading: false, isSuccess: false},
    data: {
      controls: {
        dropdowns: null,
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I think the issue is how you are registering the feature state. You are registering the state as root but accessing it as a feature state. Register your state as `StoreModule.forFeature` - Refer - https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#register-feature-state

Comment: @user2216584 I'm looking at their [`forRoot` documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#registering-root-state) and what I have seems right. I use that `forFeature` syntax to register separate modules.

Comment: 1) please provide your `initialState` value. 2) you shouldn't mutate `draftState` inside your reducer, but return a new `{...draftState, ...}` value. 3) Advice: deep nested objects in store could be pain to manage.

Comment: @ThierryFalvo I am directly updating `draftState` in exact accordance with the immer documentation. What's the problem?

Comment: @ThierryFalvo I've added `initialState`

Comment: @1252748, I've updated the answer based on your new request.

Answer (score 2):

Because you updated your question the answer is https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged

it allows to emit values only when they have been changed.

```js
store.pipe(
  map(state => state.feature.something),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
)
```

requires `state.feautre.something` to have been changed.

The right way would be to use `createSelector` function that returns memorized selectors that works in the same way as `distinctUntilChanged`.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think so. I have added the `initialState` as a default to the reducer's state parameter. I have updated with relevant code.

Comment: do you have a reducer function after it https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function ?
`export const appReducer = produce(...` isn't enough. It's from this part `Note: The exported reducer function is necessary as function calls are not supported by the AOT compiler.`

Comment: I don't follow. I _am_ using the memoized `createSelector` function.

Comment: okay, now I see that you changed the question. And my question is - what do you want to achieve? Because at the beginning it was about an error, now about preventing selectors. The code you have above works as normal state. If you want to select from store once - add `take(1)` to the pipe `.pipe(select(getConfigDropdowns), take(1))`.

Comment: Changed my question—what are you on about? I've added some code to it is the only edits I've made. The error was occurring in a selector, which I want to prevent. I've read your answer and comments several times. I don't think we're on the same page. Avoiding these selector errors should be achievable without piping a bunch of additional RxJS operators

Comment: that's what confuses, because your code returns getConfigDropdowns only once even there're several `LoadAppConfig` emits. And that's why I asked what the question is, because code works :)
when I'm subscribed to getConfigDropdowns I get dropdowns only when they've been changed, so I think it works as expected. But if you want just to take them once and close the stream - you can use `take(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` operator to make sure it emits values only for valid values, and after that you can use `pluck` operator to emit value of respective nested property.

```
store.pipe(
  filter(value => state.feature.something),
  pluck('feature', 'something'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dispatch` method is async.
So:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new appActions.LoadAppConfig());
  this.store
    .pipe(select(appSelectors.getConfigDropdowns))
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('OnInit Dropdowns Data: ', data);
    });
}
```

Here the subscription runs faster than the `dispatch` so the select returns with null value from your initial state. Simply check this in the selector or add initial state. EX:

```js
const getAppFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<IAppState>('app');

export const getAppConfig = createSelector(getAppFeatureState, state => {
  return state.appConfig.data;
});

export const getConfigControls = createSelector(getAppConfig, state => {
  console.log({ state }) // logs values from initial state
  return state.controls;
});

export const getConfigDropdowns = createSelector(
  getConfigControls,
  state => state ? state.dropdown : null,
);
```

Comment: If false/falsy is returned early from one of these selectors, does it not trigger the subscription? I mean, I feel like you'd still have to filter this like`pipe(filter(Boolean))` or something, no?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I took a look again in code and updated my answer.

Can you try below given sample.

```
this.store
  .pipe(
    // Here `isStarted` will be boolean value which will enable and disable selector. 
    //This can be derived from initial state, if null it wont go to next selector
    switchMap(data => {
      if (isStarted) {
        return never();
      } else {
        return of(data);
      }
    }),
    switchMap(data => select(appSelectors.getConfigDropdowns))
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("OnInit Dropdowns Data: ", data);
  });
```

Comment: you don't return `draftState` with immer you just mutate it.

Comment: yes but need to return state from the reducer. that is missing same time.. mutate is not recommended. unpredictable behavior

Comment: `We'll explore how to perform side effects in the advanced walkthrough. For now, just remember that the reducer must be pure. Given the same arguments, it should calculate the next state and return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation.`

https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: I have overseen you entire question. I have updated my answer. Please check now.